# Initialize a byte array manually to test the changes

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, initialization

I am using a SOAP webservice to get a byte array, which is written to a file in pdf format(done programmatically).Now I am getting the byte array in the following format-"JVBERi0xLjUKJeLjz9MKMyAwIG9iago8PC9Db2xvc.....KOTMzMzIKJSVFT0YK". I want to write a sample program

```
FileOutputStream outputstream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\temp\report.pdf");
outputstream.write(bytes);
outputstream.close();
```

But I am not understanding how to initalise  **bytes** (in my sample program) to the byte array recieved over the service manually(it is done through xml annotation binding in the project).Could someone help me with this please?

Comment: HI!
Your question is not clear, What do you mean by `array recieved over the service manually`?

Comment: Could you then add code which load this byte array?

Comment: `"JVBERi0xLjUKJeLjz9MKMyAwIG9iago8PC9Db2xvc.....KOTMzMzIKJSVFT0YK"` ... is this a base64 encoded byte array perhaps?

Comment: @Naya we are just using the getter method of the particular xml element to write it in to the pdf file.

Comment: @rcgeorge23 I am not quite sure about the any encoding done but in the project code we just write it using write method FileOutputStream.

Comment: The ask is not clear. But if you want to convert the incoming string to a byte array use, string get bytes method.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes()